# Why does Microsoft IE change the order of an object's keys on insertion/deletion?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

For Microsoft IE, if inserting an element with deleted key and total element is greater than 31 then the ordering of JSON object will be reversed.

*To date, this problem occurred in IE only.*
***And, it does not happens in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera,*** the element is inserted as the ordering of insertion.

This issue can be reproduced by running the test codes below on different browser with different "count" value.

```
<script>
    var temp = {};
    var count = 31;
    add = function(){
        for(var i=0; i<count;i++)
        {
            var id = "id:"+i;
            var c = {};
            c[id] = "value:"+i;
            console.log("push at " + i + " = " + id);
            _.extend(temp, c);
        }
    }
    display = function(){
        var i=0;
        $.each(temp,function(key, value){
            console.log("list at "+i+" = " + key);
            i++;
        });
    }
    deletion = function(){
        var i=0;
        $.each(temp,function(key, value){
            console.log("delete at " + i+ " = "+key);
            delete temp[key];
            i++;    
        });
    }
    add();
    display();
    deletion();
    add();
    display();
</script>
```

*Please note that ordering is not important when pushing an element to JSON object according to ECMA standard.*

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: There's no JSON in your code, and JavaScript object ordering is defined by implementation. There's no requirement in the ECMA standard for it to work the same way between implementations.

Comment: JSON object is built on run time as shown in code. Perhaps, I should called it "[object Object]".

Comment: No, still no JSON. JSON is a way of storing objects as strings; you have not used it in the code above. What you have there is just "an object".

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, that's not a JSON object, it's a JS object. JSON is a serialization format for passing around strings of text that contain encoded data; an object in JS is an actual object, not a string representation of one.

Secondly, JS objects (and, as it happens, JSON objects) are explicitly defined as *unordered sets of key-value pairs*. You can iterate over them, but you cannot rely on getting the elements in any particular order.

A naive implementation of JS would simply add each new key-value pair to the end of a list. But this means that whenever you access a particular key, the entire list must be searched to find it; clearly, this would get very inefficient for objects with lots of keys. So instead, an optimised JS engine will do something cleverer - it might store the keys in alphabetical order, so it can perform a binary search for the key; or more likely, it will use some hashing function and sort by that, so that the binary search is more likely to reach optimum efficiency.

For small objects, there is a different efficiency concern: memory usage. Ideally, an object would occupy a single contiguous chunk of memory, surrounded on either side by other objects or data. When you add more keys, or longer values, the memory for an object needs to grow, and moving the whole thing to a bigger space will be slow and leave a gap at the old location, so again, the engine needs to do something cleverer. This will probably include pre-allocating extra space to grow into, and reusing space vacated by deleted items (in, again, an order that maximises the efficiency of the engine).

All of this will be being dynamically tuned inside the engine based on particular circumstances, which will include the number and size of key-value pairs, and even what the object is being used for. It's therefore no surprise at all that beyond a certain size, under the influence of repeated removals and insertions, a modern browser selects a strategy that ends up in reverse order.

The bottom line is **don't make any assumption about the order of keys in an object**. As far as your code is concerned, they are effectively in a random order.

Comment: Perhaps, you are correct and I don't have in deep understanding of browser implementation. However, why is it be reversed on IE after 31 element ???

Comment: @MarcelDavid: Who knows... maybe some optimization where small objects use a different internal data structure from large ones and when they change structures, they copy the items over in reverse for performance reasons.

Comment: Interesting... when i use >999 object elements i could gain e implicit ordering relation from other browser but not IE. Thank you for sharing this information to me.